# How to read MIDI notes with NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, midi, naudio

I need to read MIDI files in order to do further processing with the notes.

I tried to do so with NAudio like this

```
MidiFile midi = new MidiFile("Test.mid");
foreach (MidiEvent note in midi.Events[1])
{
    Console.Write(note.AbsoluteTime.ToString().PadRight(10));
    Console.WriteLine(note.DeltaTime);
}
```

I was hoping to get the start of the note and the duration, but I get odd values, starting at **34654** (why?):

[image]

**Question:**

I need every MIDI note and

- The start time
- The length
- The channel index

How can I get the correct values using NAudio? If you have suggestions for a different library, please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: look at the Audio file explorer demo app that comes with the NAudio source code. This does exactly what you are after for MIDI files

Comment: ^ http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AudioFileInspector/FileInspectors/MidiFileInspector.cs  for anyone having trouble finding it.  Also http://opensebj.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/naudio-tutorial-7-basics-of-midi-files.html is a good resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The midi file spec works with delta-times for each event. So a delta time of 0 means at the same time as the previous event. How much actual time the delta-time represents depends on information in the midi file header.

Here is some info on the inner workings of midi files.
http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: So delta time 0 means the same as before. Why does the absolute time start with a value like  34654?

Comment: Also, how are pauses represented here?

Comment: Ok, never mind. The console just cut it off. I think the info you provided is enough for me to go with. Thank you!

Comment: That site keeps moving around. http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/files/midifile.htm